# Show that the interior of an ellipse ${(x,y): (\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2\leq 1}$ is convex.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need help with proving that this set is convex. How would you show that the interior of this ellipse ${(x,y): (\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2\leq 1}$ is convex? Using the $tP+(1-t)Q∈C$ proof.

Answer (score 1):

You just use the convexity of the function $x^2$ as follows:

\begin{eqnarray} \frac{(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(ty_1+(1-t)y_2)^2}{b^2} 
& \stackrel{x^2\; convex}{\leq} & \frac{tx_1^2+(1-t)x_2^2}{a^2} + \frac{ty_1^2+(1-t)y_2^2}{b^2} \\
& = & t\underbrace{\left[\left(\frac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y_1}{b}\right)^2\right]}_{\leq 1} + (1-t)\underbrace{\left[\left(\frac{x_2}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y_2}{b}\right)^2\right]}_{\leq 1} \\
& \leq & 1 + (1-t) = 1
\end{eqnarray}